# JHipster - No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory' available

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, tomcat, jhipster, undertow

I am developing a JHipster application. I have issues configuring SSL.
I have generated a certificate using Letsencrypt and modified my yaml production file (enabled SSL).
But when I deploy on my Tomcat I have the following exception:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in io.github.jhipster.security.ssl.UndertowSSLConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory' that could not be found.
The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'undertowServletWebServerFactory' in 'ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration.EmbeddedUndertow' 
    not loaded because 
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory; SearchStrategy: current) 
    found beans of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory' tomcatServletWebServerFactory
Action:
Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory' in your configuration.

22-Nov-2019 05:47:32.154 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'undertowSSLConfiguration' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.5.46/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/jhipster-framework-3.0.5.jar!/io/github/jhipster/security/ssl/UndertowSSLConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1658)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1217)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
        ... 32 more
```

It seems it expects `UndertowServletWebServerFactory` but has found `tomcatServletWebServerFactory`. I have searched on the net, on JHipster documentation, but I do not find anything related to these issues.

Could someone please help me?
Thank you

Comment: JHipster by default embeds Undertow server, any reason why you want to deploy in Tomcat rather than running JHipster app as an executable jar?

Comment: There is no specific reason. I deployed on my tomcat and everything was ok in HTTP so I continued using it. The problem occured while introducing HTTPS. I'll trying then as executable jar; I hope it will solve my issue. Thank you

Comment: Executable jar is the deployment model pushed by JHipster and Spring Boot. While it is perfectly doable to deploy in Tomcat or any other server, it will require more work on your side.

Comment: Thank you Gael, it works great :-) and http is redirected to https. My only issue left is that I now have to specify port 80/8080 else I can not reach the site

Comment: I don't understand your issue, maybe open another question with more details

Comment: Yes, my current question has been answered. Thank you